# plot in jupyter shows unexpected line (x=y)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

A bit stuck with this:

I've got two numpy arrays of equal size

```
x [  10   11   12 ... 9997 9998 9999]
y [  0  11   0 ... 610 610 610]
```

When i plot them, I get the following

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

[image]

The line `x=y` is not expected, nor desired. Any ideas?

x and y are being generated in the following function

```
x = np.arange(10,10000)
y = np.arange(10,10000)
def fun():
    prime_count = 0
    for i in range (10, 10000):
        x[i-10] = i
        if(sp.ntheory.isprime(i)):
        # i is the current prime
            if((i%6) == 5):
                prime_count+=1
                y[i-10] = prime_count
#                 print prime_count
        else:
            y[i-10] = prime_count
#                 print "prime disvisible by 6 with remainder 5: ", i
    print prime_count;
    print "printing x", x
    print "printing y", y
    return x, y
pi65();
```

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   Without the actual data that you use to make the plot, the best anyone can do is guess.  My guess is that the values in `x` do not increase monotonically (i.e. `x` is not sorted in increasing order).

Comment: hi @WarrenWeckesser thank you for the feedback, I've updated the question with how the two arrays are generated.

Comment: After taking a proper look at my function I saw that I was missing a line which populated my y array with the right value. the array was initialised with np arrange so some values were not replaced showing an x=y value
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After taking a proper look at my function I saw that I was missing a line (after the second if) which populated my y array with the right value. the array was initialised with np arrange so some values were not replaced showing an x=y value
Thank you